# Simple react counter

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to learning React and have chosen to start off using Visual Studio's .NET + React template, which gave me this chunk of code in a .tsx file as a demonstration of how to make a simple button that increments a counter:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

interface CounterState
{
    currentCount: number;
}

export class Home extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, CounterState>
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = { currentCount: 0 };
    }

    public render()
    {
        return <div>
            <h1>Counter</h1>
            <p>This is a simple example of a React component.</p>
            <p>Current count: <strong>{this.state.currentCount}</strong></p>
            <button onClick={() => { this.incrementCounter() }}>Increment</button>
        </div>;
    }

    incrementCounter()
    {
        this.setState
        ({
            currentCount: this.state.currentCount + 1
        });
    }
}
```

Which produces [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdsuM.png) that just increments the number when the button is pressed.

What I'm confused about is why there needs to be an interface and 'state'. If I were to have implemented it myself, it would've looked like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

export class Home extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>>
{
    currentCount: number;

    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.currentCount = 0;
    }

    public render()
    {
        return <div>
            <h1>Counter</h1>
            <p>This is a simple example of a React component.</p>
            <p>Current count: <strong>{this.currentCount}</strong></p>
            <button onClick={() => { this.incrementCounter() }}>Increment</button>
        </div>;
    }

    incrementCounter()
    {
        this.currentCount += 1;
        this.render();
    }
}
```

Except this doesn't do anything - the counter always stays at zero.
The code isn't being completely skipped over though: adding in `console.log(this.currentCount);` inside `incrementCounter()` does in fact show the count going up with each button press in the debug console.

So what is special about using an interface here? And why does the increment need to be done via setState rather than a direct variable increment?

Comment: Without doing ``setState`` react would never know when to rerender your component with new state values. That is why state is necessary.Please read official react docs properly

Comment: Ugh... React looks horrible with typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`React` makes use of the state to store data needed by the component in it.
You will see a common pattern when developing `React` applications where the `props`, or parts of it, get stored in the `state`, since `props` should be immutable, but the `state` is not.

That is where the built in function `setState()` kicks in. With it you can alter the stored data. Additionally it triggers a rerender everytime you alter the data stored in the `state` via `setState()`.

This is especially useful when handling `controlled components`, like `input` elements in a `form`.

You should take a look at this [Tutorial](https://tylermcginnis.com/courses/react-fundamentals/), it helped me a lot when starting to learn `React`.

Answer (score 0):

setState is used to trigger a method called shouldComponentUpdate which decides if the component should be updated / re-rendered by looking at the data in this.state to see if it was changed.

Comment: That is not correct ... the rerender happens anyways, but `React` makes use of several lifecylce methods where you can hook in. One of those is `shouldComponentUpdate()`. With this method you can check the changes made to the `state` or `props` and trigger a rerendering manually (or hinder it).

Comment: ok yes,theres a lot going on when learning React my explanation isn't exact (still learning myself) I used https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html as a point of reference.

Comment: Well technically, shouldComponentUpdate defaults to true. So if React calls shouldComponentUpdate behind the scenes everytime there is a state change, then he would be correct.

Comment: But I would say I can't really accept this answer, as it makes it seem like setState only triggers that one method. There is a lot more behind the scenes as the lifecycle points out.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

React updates it's virtual DOM when there is a state change. Specifically, it reacts to any state properties (under `this.state`) for that change. After these are set in the constructor, you update the state itself via. `this.setState()` which allows React to make the proper updates to the actual DOM without performance bottlenecks.

Also, never call `render()` yourself as you did with your version of `incrementCounter`. This is a hook for the React framework to use when rendering the current component you are working on.

---

To answer your question though, `interface` is actually more optional than anything. I've developed a few React apps and have yet to use it.

...and as for using `setState`, refer to the above statements I made.